# Passportjs Invalid login due to multiple username in database (nodejs, jade, npm)

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js

I am getting errors when I try to login with the registration values for my site which I use expressjs, passport and alot other modules. I observe, this is a result of multiple usernames of the same username in the database(MongoDB). Is there a solution where passport authentication recognizes the both username separately or is there a way I can refuse registrations that logins have been taken using passportjs

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest: './uploads'});
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var User = require('../models/user');

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('register', { title: 'Register' });
});

router.post('/register', upload.single('image'), function(req, res, next) {
  var name = req.body.name;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var password2 = req.body.password2;

  if (req.file) {
    console.log("Uploading...");
    var img_name = req.file.filename;
  } else {
    console.log("U don fuck up uploads");
    var img_name = "no_image.jpg";
  }
  // Form validator
  req.checkBody('name', 'name field is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email', 'email field is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('username', 'username field is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password', 'password field is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password2', 'confirm the password is the same').equals(req.body.password);
  req.checkBody('password', 'password must contain uppercase, lowercase, number and atleast 8 characters').matches(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/, "i");

  //Check errors
  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (errors){
    console.log('You got Errors');
    res.render('register', {errors : errors});
  }else {
    console.log("No errors");
    var newUser = new User({
      name: name,
      email: email,
      username: username,
      password: password,
      img_name: img_name
    });

    User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(user);
    });

    req.flash('success', 'You are now registered and can login!');

    res.location('/');
    res.redirect('/');
  }
});


router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login', { title: 'Login Page' });
});

router.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', {failureRedirect:'/users/login', failureFlash:'Invalid username or password'}),
  function(req, res) {
    req.flash("success", "You are now logged in!")
    res.redirect('/');
});

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done){
  User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!user){
      return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User cannot enter!'});
    }
    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
      if (err) return done(err);
      if (isMatch){
        return done(null, user);
      }else {
        return done(null, false, {message:'Invalid Password'});
      }
    });
  });
}));

router.get('/logout', function (req, res){
  req.logout();
  req.flash('success', 'You are logged out!');
  res.redirect('/users/login');
})

module.exports = router;
```

Kindly pay most of your attention to this:

```
router.post('/register', upload.single('image'), function(req, res, next) {
  var name = req.body.name;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var password2 = req.body.password2;

  if (req.file) {
    console.log("Uploading...");
    var img_name = req.file.filename;
  } else {
    console.log("U don fuck up uploads");
    var img_name = "no_image.jpg";
  }
  // Form validator
  req.checkBody('name', 'name field is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email', 'email field is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('username', 'username field is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password', 'password field is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password2', 'confirm the password is the same').equals(req.body.password);
  req.checkBody('password', 'password must contain uppercase, lowercase, number and atleast 8 characters').matches(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/, "i");

  //Check errors
  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (errors){
    console.log('You got Errors');
    res.render('register', {errors : errors});
  }else {
    console.log("No errors");
    var newUser = new User({
      name: name,
      email: email,
      username: username,
      password: password,
      img_name: img_name
    });

    User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(user);
    });

    req.flash('success', 'You are now registered and can login!');

    res.location('/');
    res.redirect('/');
  }
});
```

Comment: This is very confusing `multiple usernames of the same username?`, can you clear this up with an example

Comment: Yes it seems if multiple username present in the db caused the error so I want to prevent registration if username is already present.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend within your `register` route adding a database query to check if the username already exists before creating a new record with an identical username.

Here's an example of what you could potentially do.

```js
const user = await User.findOne({ username });
if (user) {
  req.flash('fail', 'This username was previously registered!');
  res.redirect('/register');
}
User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
  if (err) throw err;
    console.log(user);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Jasonandmonte answer is spot on, just to add to it as there is another way to configure this as you can use `unique: true` on your `username property` as it will automatically create an index and check against saved `users` automatically (as a pre hook).

This will save you writing additional `.find()` statements inside your code, which will get harder to debug/maintain nestings if your application grows.

Read more about SchemaType's [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#schematype-options)

Quick example would be

```
const User= new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    index: true,
    unique: true // Unique index. If you specify `unique: true`
    // specifying `index: true` is optional if you do `unique: true`
  }
});
```